# Excel : use averageif with formulas on the range

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula, average

I have data that I get on a quarter basis (e.g. `2019-T2, 2019-T1, 2018-T4` and so on), [data here](https://www.insee.fr/fr/statistiques/serie/telecharger/010599833?ordre=antechronologique&transposition=donneescolonne&periodeDebut=1&anneeDebut=1998&periodeFin=2&anneeFin=2019). 
I want to get yearly averages.

I have managed to do that in two steps :

- Creating a year column derived from the quarter : `D4=VALUE(LEFT(A4;4))`
- Calculating an average after adding my years column in E : `F4=AVERAGEIF(D4:D89;E4;B4:B89)`

But I do not manage to condense it in one formula, how is it doable? In particular, I get an error when trying to plug the first in the second?

[image]

[image]
Note that I have excel in French so I might have made error in translating function names

Comment: How did you combine them? Can you post a screenshot of your data?

Comment: I have added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A FRENCH MESSAGE WILL FOLLOW

You can use Wildwards :

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A,"*"&LEFT(A2,4)&"*",B:B)
```

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5Msx.png)

Je suppose qu'en français cela donnerait :

```
=MOYENNE.SI(A:A,"*"&GAUCHE(A2,4)&"*",B:B)
```

Or you can also use this if you want a column with the dates :

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A,"*"&E2&"*",B:B)
```

[image]

If you dont want a column with the dates, you ll need a trick to remplace the E2 by 2019,2018 ... when you drag down. You have different possibilities :

```
=LEFT($A$2,4)-(1*(ROW(A2)-2))
```

Or

```
=2021-ROW(E2)
```

Don't forget your wildcards !

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A,"*"&LEFT($A$2,4)-(1*(ROW(A2)-2))&"*",B:B)
```

[image]

or :

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A,"*"&2021-ROW(E2)&"*",B:B)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but your solution does not completely match my need, as I want to reduce the number of lines. I want to have only one year per line, as in my first image. So something like : `"*"&GAUCHE(A2,4)&"*" = E2` with E2=2019, E3=2018 and so on. And for English, it is unfortunately locked by my company policy.

Comment: As I said, I am pretty sure you can use the english formula in the French Excel. But anyway.
I edited my first message with alternative solutions.

Comment: Now perfect, thank you a lot. If you have some extra time, could you just explain why my attempt to plug the two formulas into one another did not work and why I had to use Wildwards ? On a sidenote, I might have some parameters to check but english formulas do not work in my setup right now.

Comment: On your first screenshot, I can see you used : moyenne.si(valeur(gauche(...etc. in the cell G4. I am not sure in French, but in english when you use averageif, the first argument is the range of cells you want evaluated (in your case : 2019 -T2 ... etc). That is why you have the error #name. You can learn more about averageif here : https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-averageif-function. Wildcards are used to perfect your searchs : https://exceljet.net/glossary/wildcard. In your case you need the second wildcard so Excel will accept 2019-T2 as 2019.

Comment: I am French living in Canada, thats why i know both Excel versions. Here, we use commas (,) instead of Semicolons (;). Replace my commas with semicolons ! =AVERAGEIF(A:A,"*"&LEFT($A$2,4)-(1*(ROW(A2)-2))&"*",B:B) should be =AVERAGEIF(A:A;"*"&LEFT($A$2;4)-(1*(ROW(A2)-2))&"*";B:B). Do not forget that my table starts at the second row while yours starts at the fourth. I am at work right now with an English Excel but I have a French version at home. Let me know if it is working :)

Comment: Yes I guessed I plugged it wrong. But I confirm as it is that formulas do not work in English for me : even a simple `=AVERAGE(B2:B4)` does not work with me

Comment: Good to know ! I assume you can just translate. Just to be sure : does it work in French ?  =MOYENNE.SI(A:A;""&GAUCHE($A$2;4)-(1*(LIGNE(A2)-2))&"";B:B). I assume Row is Ligne in French, but I am not sure at all.

Comment: With the `*` it does ! Thank you a lot.